# How to logon with local account? RODC "There are no logon servers to process your request"

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, rodc

I have a site-to-site VPN, writeable DC in the main office, Read-only DC in a branch office.

Today the VPN went down, but I couldn't log in to the read-only DC - the error message came up `There are no logon servers to process your request.`

Since the RODC is a domain controller, there is no local administrator.

How can I ensure that I am always able to log on to the RODC with a known account in an emergency if the writable DC is not available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a GC - Global Catalog - to process logon requests ;)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the PRP to allow a certain account's password to be cached.